# How to insert date value in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my html code. I am trying to insert a date value in a database but I can't see it how it is possible.

```
<select name="date">
  <option value="selected"> Day </option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2"> 2 </option>
  <option value="3"> 3 </option>
  <option value="4"> 4 </option>
</select> 

<select name="date">
  <option value="selected"> Month </option>
  <option value="jan"> jan </option>
  <option value="feb"> feb </option>
  <option value="mar"> mar </option>
  <option value="april"> april </option>
</select> 

<select name="date">
  <option value="selected"> year </option>
  <option value="1990"> 1990 </option>
  <option value="1991"> 1991 </option>
  <option value="1992"> 1992 </option>
  <option value="1993"> 1993 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: And where is your `PHP` code? What have you tried?

Comment: You can also create a input box, type date...

Comment: This is core basic php: take data from a form and do something with it. Just because your values are dates doesn't make it magically different from any OTHER form-to-database submission.

Comment: Hint: If you named your components `date_day`, `date_month` and `date_year` you'd have an easier time processing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy just use serialize() and unserialize().
and also [] this array sign in you name like it .
**here is example:**

```
<select name="date[]">
                    <option value="selected"> Day </option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2"> 2 </option>
                    <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                    <option value="4"> 4 </option>
                </select> 

                <select name="date[]">
                    <option value="selected"> Month </option>
                    <option value="jan"> jan </option>
                    <option value="feb"> feb </option>
                    <option value="mar"> mar </option>
                    <option value="april"> april </option>
                </select> 

               <select name="date[]">
                    <option value="selected"> year </option>
                    <option value="1990"> 1990 </option>
                    <option value="1991"> 1991 </option>
                    <option value="1992"> 1992 </option>
                    <option value="1993"> 1993 </option>
                </select>
```

and add this name key in serialize() function and unserialize your database value using unserialize() function.

**insert**

```
 $date = serialize($_POST['date']);
```

**View**

```
$date = unserialize($date);
            echo $date[0]."/ ".$date[1]."/ ".$date[2];
```

Comment: This should be in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), or `YYYY-MM-DD` for it to work best with a SQL database.

Comment: it's working currectly

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several ways.

**Way 1:** You can provide different names to select inputs like-

```
<select name="dd">
    <option value="selected"> Day </option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2"> 2 </option>
    <option value="3"> 3 </option>
    <option value="4"> 4 </option>
</select> 

<select name="mm">
    <option value="selected"> Month </option>
    <option value="jan"> jan </option>
    <option value="feb"> feb </option>
    <option value="mar"> mar </option>
    <option value="april"> april </option>
</select> 

<select name="yy">
    <option value="selected"> year </option>
    <option value="1990"> 1990 </option>
    <option value="1991"> 1991 </option>
    <option value="1992"> 1992 </option>
    <option value="1993"> 1993 </option>
</select>
```

After submitting the form you can receive the values in **php** as follows.

```
$date = $_POST['dd'].'/'.$_POST['mm'].'/'.$_POST['yy'];
```

**Way 2:** You can name them as array as follows.

```
<select name="date[]">
    <option value="selected"> Day </option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2"> 2 </option>
    <option value="3"> 3 </option>
    <option value="4"> 4 </option>
</select> 

<select name="date[]">
    <option value="selected"> Month </option>
    <option value="jan"> jan </option>
    <option value="feb"> feb </option>
    <option value="mar"> mar </option>
    <option value="april"> april </option>
</select> 

<select name="date[]">
    <option value="selected"> year </option>
    <option value="1990"> 1990 </option>
    <option value="1991"> 1991 </option>
    <option value="1992"> 1992 </option>
    <option value="1993"> 1993 </option>
</select>
```

In php you can receive them as follows

```
$date = $_POST['date'][0].'/'.$_POST['date'][1].'/'.$_POST['date'][2];
```

**Note:** I recommend you to use input field with type `date` or use a date picker in text input field.

Comment: This should be in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), or `YYYY-MM-DD` for it to work best with a SQL database.

Comment: Then you can set numeric values in the month options, then concatenate them as your expected format.

Comment: Exactly. This would be a lot cleaner if the month values were numerical. The display label is just for human use.

Comment: So you should use like this- 
<option value="01"> Jan </option>

Comment: That would make things considerably less complicated. I also don't trust browsers to return things in any particular order, the `[]` notation is intended for checkboxes, so naming these selectors differently would also help.